# HTTP testing on the command line, is there something better than cURL?

Tags: http, testing, command-line

Is there a command line utility where you can simply set up an HTTP request and have the trace simply output back to the console?

Also specifying the method simply would be a great feature instead of the method being a side effect.

I can get all the information I need with cURL but I can't figure out a way to just display it without dumping everything to files.

I'd like the output to show the sent headers the received headers and the body of the message.

There must be something out there but I haven't been able to google for it. Figured I should ask before going off and writing it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dislike answering my own question but c-smile's answer lead me down the right track:

Short answer shell script over cURL:

```
curl --dump-header - "$@"
```

The - [dash] meaning stdout is a convention I was unaware of but also works for wget and a number of other unix utilities. It is apparently not part of the shell but built into each utility. The wget equivalent is:

```
wget --save-headers -qO - "$@"
```

Comment: Answering your own question is highly encouraged! Future people googling this (like me) will thank you. Except I'm not finding the thing I had in mind -- someone wrote a really slick tool for this that could deal with cookies and everything that I'm having a hell of a time finding.

Comment: I think the `curl` solution you were looking for was the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15138200/96656

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `wget`:
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Wgetrc-Commands ?
Like `wget --save-headers` ...

Answer (score 2):

To include the HTTP headers in the output (as well as the server response), just use `curl`’s `-i`/`--include` option. For example:

```
curl -i "http://www.google.com/"
```

Here’s what `man curl` says about this setting:

```
   -i/--include
      (HTTP)  Include  the  HTTP-header in the output. The HTTP-header
      includes things like server-name, date of  the  document,  HTTP-
      version and more...

      If  this  option  is  used  twice, the second will again disable
      header include.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try http, e.g.

`http -v example.org`

Further into at https://httpie.org

It even includes a page to try online:

https://httpie.org/run

Answer (score 0):

Telnet has for long been a well-known (though now forgotten, I guess) tool for looking at a web page. The general idea is to telnet to the http port, to type an http 1.1 GET command, and then to see the served page on the screen.

A good detailed explanation is [**http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279466**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279466)

A  [**Google search**](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=netgear+fvs318g+user+manual&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGHP_enUS431&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=telnet%20to%20web%20page%20get&xhr=t&q=telnet+web+page+get&cp=7&pf=p&sclient=psy&rlz=1B3GGHP_enUS431&source=hp&aq=0j&aqi=&aql=&oq=telnet+web+page+get&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c47720ba43ce4197&bs=1) yields a whole bunch more.

Answer (score 0):

Use telnet on port 80

For example:

```
telnet telehack.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
host: telehack.com
<CR>
<CR>
```

`<CR>` means Enter